# String.Format count the number of expected args

Tags: c#, .net, string

Is it possible to count the number of expected args/params in a string for `String.Format()`?

For example: `"Hello {0}. Bye {1}"` should return a count of 2.

I need to display an error before the `string.Format()` throws an exception.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why not simply catch the exception and display the error then?

Comment: Sorry, but why do you need to do this? :P I see no way to do this short of parsing out the string. What should "{0} {0}" return? Wouldn't it be easier to just catch the exception?

Comment: I hate to play the blame game and say that someone else wrote this code, but they did. There are a number of validations that are happening on the way that error messages are formatted and one of them is comparing the number of arguments passed with the number of expected arguments. So there already is a solution. I'm just trying to find a better way of doing it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156497/string-has-how-many-parameters

Comment: I would take another approach. But the answer to your question is that you'd just need to parse the string. You need to handle cases like "{{0}}", which does not count. You also need to handle cases like "{0:#,##0}". That's your answer. Again, I wouldn't take this approach.

Comment: *"Please don't ask me why I need to do this"* - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/03/23/558887.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a better way to count string format placeholders in a string in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948303/is-there-a-better-way-to-count-string-format-placeholders-in-a-string-in-c)

Comment: I did try searching before posting the question here. But thanks for the link

Comment: The correct way would be as Marcelo Cantos states (catch exception).  What if a value is reused, for example the string format is "{0}={1},{0}" so 3{} but 2 values. All that regex code when you could just try/catch.

Comment: @EdS. Excellent article. Link is dead - here's the Archive.org version: https://web.archive.org/web/20100806024009/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/03/23/558887.aspx

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use a regex, something like {(.*?)} and then just count the matches.  If you need to handle cases like {0} {0} (which I guess should return 1) then that makes it a little more difficult, but you could always put all of the matches in a list an do a Linq select distinct on it.  I'm thinking something like the code below:

```
var input = "{0} and {1} and {0} and {2:MM-dd-yyyy}";
var pattern = @"{(.*?)}";
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
var totalMatchCount = matches.Count;
var uniqueMatchCount = matches.OfType<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).Distinct().Count();
Console.WriteLine("Total matches: {0}", totalMatchCount);
Console.WriteLine("Unique matches: {0}", uniqueMatchCount);
```

**EDIT:**

I wanted to address some of the concerns raised in the comments.  The updated code posted below handles the cases where there are escaped bracket sequences (i.e., {{5}}), where no parameters are specified, and also returns the value of the highest parameter + 1.  The code assumes that the input strings will be well formed, but that trade off may be acceptable in some cases.  For example, if you know that the input strings are defined in an application and not generated by user input, then handling all of the edge cases may not be necessary.  It might also be possible to test all of the error messages to be generated using a unit test.  The thing I like about this solution is that it will most likely handle the vast majority of the strings that are thrown at it, and it is a simpler solution than the one identified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948303/is-there-a-better-way-to-count-string-format-placeholders-in-a-string-in-c/948667#948667) (which suggests a reimplementation of string.AppendFormat).  I would account for the fact that this code might not handle all edge cases by using a try-catch and just returning "Invalid error message template" or something to that effect.

One possible improvement for the code below would be to update the regex to not return the leading "{" characters.  That would eliminate the need for the Replace("{", string.Empty).  Again, this code might not be ideal in all cases, but I feel it adequately addresses the question as asked.

```
const string input = "{0} and {1} and {0} and {4} {{5}} and {{{6:MM-dd-yyyy}}} and {{{{7:#,##0}}}} and {{{{{8}}}}}";
//const string input = "no parameters";
const string pattern = @"(?<!\{)(?>\{\{)*\{\d(.*?)";
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
var totalMatchCount = matches.Count;
var uniqueMatchCount = matches.OfType<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).Distinct().Count();
var parameterMatchCount = (uniqueMatchCount == 0) ? 0 : matches.OfType<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).Distinct().Select(m => int.Parse(m.Replace("{", string.Empty))).Max() + 1;
Console.WriteLine("Total matches: {0}", totalMatchCount);
Console.WriteLine("Unique matches: {0}", uniqueMatchCount);
Console.WriteLine("Parameter matches: {0}", parameterMatchCount);
```

Comment: @Joe, So is there a regex that can count the no. of expected params?

Comment: @Joe, divi this will return for the string "Somestuff {5}" a value of 1... aren't you interested in 5, instead of 1?

Comment: @Deepee1 - Somestuff{5} should return a value of 6 and not 5. But yes, it should return a 6.

Comment: This helped me with some help from some links posted here. thanks

Comment: @joe please see my edits, I tried to address your concerns. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think this will handle Escape brackets and 0:0000 stuff... will give the greatest bracketed value... so in my example will give 1.

```
       //error prone to malformed brackets...
        string s = "Hello {0:C} Bye {1} {0} {{34}}";

        int param = -1;
        string[] vals = s.Replace("{{", "").Replace("}}", "").Split("{}".ToCharArray());
        for (int x = 1; x < vals.Length-1; x += 2)
        {
            int thisparam;
            if (Int32.TryParse(vals[x].Split(',')[0].Split(':')[0], out thisparam) && param < thisparam)
                param = thisparam;
        }
        //param will be set to the greatest param now.
```

Comment: MessageBox.Show(String.Format("yopa {{0}}","test")); outputs "yopa {0}" so it does handle the escape. I misspoke nested, I meant escape.

Comment: This is brilliant and much more easier to read than RegEx approach.