# Is there way to get max index parameter for pattern of the MessageFormat object?

Tags: java, messageformat

Is there way to get max index parameter for pattern of the MessageFormat object?
for example:

1. `"Dear {0}, some text {0} text"` -> 1
2. `"Dear {0}, some text {1} text"` -> 2
3. `"{0,choice,0#0 User|1#User|1<{1} Users}"` -> 2

Comment: [Very similar question and possible suitable answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989106/string-format-count-the-number-of-expected-args). Basically, use a regex on the string before passing it to the MessageFormat

Comment: could you please help me to write regex with the same kind of expression? It you take a look deeper on your example, you may notice that it does not cover example 3. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Nope, not something I have the time for. Good luck

Comment: Are you sure the third one is correct? Shouldn' t is `"{0,choice,0#0 User|1#User|1<{0} Users}"`, is it?

Comment: yes, please take a look at the doc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html

Comment: Sure, but https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html there is this row that is similar to yours, but different: more similar to mine: `form.applyPattern( "There {0,choice,0#are no files|1#is one file|1<are {0,number,integer} files}.");` it says that if the number is _0_ then write _are no files_ , if is _1_ then _one file_ else _are n files_ but the last params is again **0** not **1** as in your code; so are you sure that your code is correct?

Comment: Sure but depend on condition (for different languages) result maybe different. You mean the end result, if I understand you right. If the first template was used , result is 1, if the second result is 2. I would like to know the max value before apply MessageFormat. I wrote only 3 examples but it would be nice to cover the whole format MessageFormat. My example relative simple. It maybe much more complex. I think regex will be very complex and it should be something simple.

Comment: if you want to know how many placeholder the message format has _before_ use it, I think you have no choice: regexp; otherwise if the messageformat is used elsewhere one time, you can use `new HashSet(Arrays.asList(messageFormat.getFormats())).size()`

Comment: yes, you are right. Or use getFormatsByArgumentIndex(). Thank you for right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you used it once you can use:

```
 MessageFormat format = new MessageFormat("Hello {0}, {1}");
// here somewhere you use it
 System.out.println(String.format("Get max index -- %d", new HashSet(Arrays.asList(format.getFormats())).size()));
```

This prints:

`Get max index -- 2`

Comment: thank you, You are right, but for the same value format = new MessageFormat("Hello {0}, {0}"); it prints 2 also